# Setting up fixtures for model translations using Mobility in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, fixtures, mobility

How do I set up fixtures for models translations in a Rails app using Mobility?

Currently, I have the following directory structure:

```
 test
   fixtures
     article
       translations.yml
     articles.yml


# test/fixtures/articles.yml

past_article:
  type: BlogPost
  author: Barney Rubble
  posted_on: <%= 5.days.ago.to_s(:db) %>
  hero_image_id: 1


# test/fixtures/article/translations.yml

past_article_translation:
  article: past_article
  locale: en
  title: Past Article Fixture
  subtitle: Temporary subtitle
  body: This is the temporary blog post content.
```

I get `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "article_translations" has no column named "article".` when trying to run my tests.

With Globalize gem, I could change the key in `translations.yml` from `article` to `globalized_model`, but that doesn't work with Mobility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `article` to `translated_model`, I believe it should work. `translated_model` is the equivalent in Mobility to `globalized_model` in Globalize.

(I don't use fixtures myself so not really familiar with syntax, but the inverse relationship from translation to model is `translated_model`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/blob/a52998479893e33a6df5bfd395f50f76884cf64e/lib/mobility/backends/active_record/table.rb#L136-L140)).

Comment: What do you use? Factory Girl/Factory Bot?

Comment: Factory Girl, but it really doesn't matter. When you're using any factory gem, you have to build actual associations, so you just need to know the table/association names, nothing else from Mobility  should really matter.